# 'Noodle' zigzagging of a mapping spectrometer

Tags: cassini, spectroscopy

During Cassini's "T16" 16th flyby of Titan on 2006 July 22, its mapping spectrometer for the first time

> utilized the 'noodle' technique of taking long, zigzagging spectra instead of single multispectral snapshot '[cubes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperspectral_imaging).'

The quotation is from Ulivi, "Robotic Exploration of the Solar System, Part 3," bottom of [page 120](https://books.google.com/books?id=F8jT1GruEckC&pg=PA120&lpg=PA120&dq=%22mapping+spectrometer%22+zigzag+noodles&source=bl&ots=w45HAET5lB&sig=ACfU3U27FhKQ0hTbz7mV5YF9siCDmja_Fg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiv6rGe-q_kAhUQVa0KHfDNDSwQ6AEwC3oECAoQAg#v=onepage&q=%22mapping%20spectrometer%22%20zigzag%20noodles&f=false).

What is the noodle technique?  What is a long zigzagging spectrum?  Why would this be preferred to conventional hyperspectral imaging?

For once the author fails to cite his sources.  Google results are awash in red herrings.

Comment: Some info here: https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/17712/cassini-noodle-mosaic-of-saturn/

Comment: Noodle, but visible spectrum. I'd done the [same](https://www.theregister.co.uk/2013/11/28/want_some_endofyear_diy_how_about_quadcopter_panoramic_pics/).   Smells like you're on to something, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pages 147-148 of
[The Cassini visual and infrared mapping spectrometer (VIMS) investigation](http://lasp.colorado.edu/~horanyi/graduate_seminar/Visual_IR_Mapping.pdf) ([original](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11214-004-1453-x)),
combined with this [image](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/17712/cassini-noodle-mosaic-of-saturn/) being called a noodle, suggests what zigzag might mean:

Instead of the usual procedure of aiming the instrument at one spot to accumulate a 64 pixel by 64 pixel by 352 spectel "data cube,"
its "along track spatial dimension" is panned across the moon's surface,
for faster and broader albeit messier data collection,
presumably when a flyby doesn't have enough time allocated to the instrument for it to run in the usual way.

---

[image]

Comment: Congratulations for tracking this down! I thought people would enjoy seeing the noodle itself, feel free to roll back.

Comment: Yeah, hunting took a while.  The cutesier the name, the harder the googling.